# How to use card view in drawable resource file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, cardview

I am using Android Studio 4.1.1. I can use card view in an empty activity XML file. But I can not use card view in a drawable resource file. Anyone can please help me?

Also, I included the dependencies as following.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `CardView` in drawables. `CardView` as the name suggests is a `View`. Drawable is a resource. Can you post more what you are hoping to achieve by including `CardView` in Drawable? I may be able to suggest an alternative way to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to use cardview in drawable. If you are looking to use it to set as a background for a view, create an xml file in layout and use the file as the background.